# Is it possible to decrypt data stored on the hard drive after it was used as LVM with encryption/LUKS?

Tags: lvm, luks

How to define encryption strength for LVM partition/hard disk in Linux?

Is it possible to decrypt the drive or its partition with the previously usage of encrypted LVM or encrypted LUKS? If yes, how to deal with that?
 Thanks.